# implementing redux middleware for dependant data

Tags: reactjs, redux

what is the best way to implement generic redux middleware which will be reside in pipeline and get triggered when there data dependency is detected

> here is scenario. i have list of notes and also note detail page on separate route (notes/:id)
>   if user comes to note detail page through notespage then it works fine since i know that note was selected/redirected from notelist and is availabe in redux store
>   but what will happen if the browser directly to earlier bookmarked link
>   how can i design a middleware such will be triggered
>   does this mean i must able to refer all actions within my middleware? 
>   so that if data does not exists trigger server call

Comment: Why middleware, not redux-saga or redux-thunk to check if note is present and call load action if not?

Comment: @elmeister  did implemented using redux-thunk basically did series of dispatches( loadDependant()). however looks a bit making call cross component calls. i have separate components with its  reducers, actions
noteslist, notedetail respectively residing in different folders  
the other point is to make it generic, so i can dispatch in my actioncreator { type:ENSURE_DEPENDANT_EXISTS },  does it make sense?

Comment: in my opinion, most easy way is to check if note is loaded in notes/:id `componentWillMount`, show loading spinner or whatever if not, and check in `componentWillReceiveProps` when note will be available - to remove spinner and show details.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [asyncConnect](https://github.com/Rezonans/redux-async-connect) here. You get the state as a parameter, you can check there if the data exist, if is not present you should load it! Here's a simple example:

```
@asyncConnect([{
  promise: ({ store: { dispatch, getState }, params }) => {
    const currentState = getState();
    const promises = [];

    if (!checkIfNoteExists(currentState)) {
      promises.push(dispatch(loadNote(params.id)));
    }

    if (!checkIfCommentsLoaded(currentState)) {
      promises.push(dispatch(loadComments()));
    }

    if (!checkIfAuthorLoaded(currentState)) {
      promises.push(dispatch(loadAuthor()));
    }

    return Promise.all(promises);
  }
}])
@connect(...)
class YouClass extends Component {
  ...
}
```

Inside `checkIfNoteExists` you need to check if the data is present on the current state, for example you could do something like this:

```
function checkIfNoteExists(state) {
  return state.note && state.note.content;
}
```

That will ensure that your data is there, if is not there then you will need to add it to the array of promises.

It's also important to note that `@asyncConnect` works on the server and on the client! Isomorphic apps FTW!

Good luck!